# Log out button doesn't work and doesn't redirect well

Tags: php

I'm working on a web project in a model-view-controller architecture, so I  have a folder with all my views and also the controller that is in the root folder.
The thing is, everything seems to work, except my log out button. I have no idea why.
Whenever I click it, I get redirected to a page that doesn't exist: presentation.php in the root folder, while this page is actually in the templates folder, as I said. Whenever I try to go to the correct page, even if I try passing through index.php, I always get redirected to this page that doesn't exist, localhost/myproject/presentation.php. 
So basically everytime I click in the logout button all my project stops working lol. I can't find the error, I have no ideia what is going on, it worked like 5 days ago.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
// In header.php, where my log out button is
<a href="controleur.php?action=Logout" id="boutton"> Log out </a>

// In the controller
case "Logout":
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            session_destroy();
            header ("Location: index.php?view=presentation");
        break;

// My index.php

if (!$view) $view = "presentation"; 

switch($view)
{   
    case "accueil" :
        include("templates/accueil.php");
    break;

    case "login" : 
        include("templates/login.php");
    break;

    case "signup" :
        include("templates/register.php");
    break;

    default : 
        if (file_exists("templates/$view.php"))
            include("templates/$view.php");
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I guess your error is in "header ("Location: index.php?view=presentation");".. I suggest you to provide entire URL to redirect, like "header ("Location: http://localhost/index.php?view=presentation");

Comment: Any rewrites happening in a `.htaccess` or something?

Comment: Add `exit;` after `header ("Location: index.php?view=presentation");` to stop further script execution.